# Json encoded data in full calendar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, json

I have such a amazing situation. I am retrieving data from MySql (with Php) and encoding it into json encoded string for inserting into jQuery full calendar. lets take a look into Php script =>

```
while ($birthday_row = $birthday_r->fetch_row()){
    $birthday_array[] = array(
        'id'  => $birthday_row[0],
        'title'     => $birthday_row[1],
        'start'     => "2012-" . $birthday_row[2] . "-" . $birthday_row[3],
    );                              
}
```

(I have no error during retrieving data from MySql , it works fine)

then encoding it with `json_encode` function like this=>

```
$k = json_encode($birthday_array);
```

and inserting it into jQuery full calendar, here is JavaScript =>

```
jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar({ // initialize full calendar
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        <?php
            echo "events:" . $k . ",";
        ?>
        eventMouseover: function(calEvent,jsEvent,view){
            $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
        }
    });
```

Reason for my wondering is that in Chrome data is inserted but in other browsers (such are firefox, opera, explorer, safari) it doesn't.

By the way here is output of `$k` variable =>

```
[{"id":"1","title":"\u10d7\u10dd\u10e0\u10dc\u10d8\u10d9\u10d4 \u10dc\u10d0\u10dc\u10dd\u10d1\u10d0\u10e8\u10d5\u10d8\u10da\u10d8","start":"2012-10-2"},{"id":"2","title":"\u10d2\u10d8\u10dd\u10e0\u10d2\u10d8 \u10d9\u10d0\u10d9\u10d0\u10e8\u10d5\u10d8\u10da\u10d8","start":"2012-10-1"},{"id":"3","title":"\u10e0\u10e3\u10d7\u10d8 root","start":"2012-9-17"},{"id":"4","title":"one one","start":"2012-9-20"},{"id":"7","title":"\u10d2\u10d8\u10dd\u10e0\u10d2\u10d8 \u10d9\u10d0\u10d9\u10d0\u10e8\u10d5\u10d8\u10da\u10d8","start":"2012-9-5"},{"id":"8","title":"\u10d2\u10d8\u10dd\u10e0\u10d2\u10d8 \u10d0\u10e4\u10e0\u10d8\u10d0\u10e8\u10d5\u10d8\u10da\u10d8","start":"2012-1-16"}]
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong , but fact is that result makes me wondered. Please help with any idea ! thanks beforehand

Comment: Deleting a question and then recreating that same question just because of down-votes is bad-form.

Comment: Reason of deleting is renewing question and simplify

Comment: You can do that just by editing.  I wouldn't do it very often if I were you, I would read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/184887), regarding what happens if you continue to do the delete-new instead of 'edit'.

Comment: @Daedalus For me rating is nothing , but I like others to be fairly with cases where nothing to be criticismed . And also what do you think am I idle for deleting and writing such big questions ? by the way thanks for advice how to renew question by editing . But honestly reason for deleting was that in previous question I have written more than it was necessary. if you have some idea for helping I will be very please , thanks

Comment: I am not speaking of rating.  I am speaking of getting banned for deleting your questions too often.

Comment: @Daedalus Okay lets cuts this dialogue out, thanks nonetheless of all

Comment: @Daedalus by the way if you were interested in this case, you can see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the reason of my problem. How amazing is it in chrome json encoded string which output is like this =>

```
[{"id":"1","title":"some","start":"2012-5-9"}]
```

works fine , but in other browsers such are firefox, opera, safari, explorer, it doesn't work.
Reason is format of date . In mentioned browsers if must be formatted like this =>

```
[{"id":"1","title":"some","start":"2012-05-09"}]
```

So here is difference between `2012-5-9` and `2012-05-09` . I really haven't had case like this was , thanks anyways if someone wanted to help me and wasted time in my question